# Why does calling anotherForm.ShowDialog() cause exceptions in System.IProgress.Report() later?

Tags: c#, winforms, task-parallel-library

I have a form with a single text box `txtOutput` and the following source:

```
public partial class frmMain : Form
{
    private IProgress reporter;

    public frmMain(string[] args)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        new anotherForm().ShowDialog();
        reporter = new Progress<string>(txtOutput.AppendText);

        Task.Run((Action)ReadReply);
    }

    private void ReadReply()
    {
        reporter.Report("test");
    }
}
```

If you run this, an exception is thrown:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'txtOutput' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.

   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.get_Handle()
   at System.Windows.Forms.TextBoxBase.GetSelectionStartAndLength(Int32& start, Int32& length)
   at System.Windows.Forms.TextBoxBase.AppendText(String text)
   at System.Progress`1.InvokeHandlers(Object state)
   at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.WaitCallback_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
   at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
   at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback()
```

If you reorder these two lines, everything works:

```
reporter = new IProgress<string>(txtOutput.AppendText);
new anotherForm().ShowDialog();
```

1. Why does `Progress.Report()` throw this exception at all? Wasn't it created to avoid this kind of exceptions?
2. Why does calling `ShowDialog()` break `IProgress.Report()`?

Comment: can you provide implementation details for IProgress<T>?. I do not recommend but you can add Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false before you do ShowDialog!

Comment: This is fake code, you can't create an instance of an interface.  Whatever class actually implements IProgress needs to do one untrivial thing, it needs to know what *specific* thread it need to invoke to in order to avoid this exception.  That requires its constructor to be called on a thread that is suitable for UI, normally always the main thread of a Winforms or WPF app.  And the app must have created a window before so it has a suitable synchronization provider (SynchronizationContext.Current).  Something went wrong there, can't be guessed at from fake code.

Comment: Fwiw, the affinity of the window to the thread is very important as well.  ShowDialog() is very forgiving, it even works on a worker thread.  Excessively bad idea however, the dialog has no owner and no Z-order relationship with any other windows so can easily disappear behind another window.  And it is very easy to hang the program with deadlock, caused by SystemEvents having to raise events on the wrong thread.  Pressing Win+L is usually good enough to cause the hang.

Comment: @HansPassant Yes, I've made a typo when I tried to minimize the example. It's `System.Progress` that is constructed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using `Progress<T>` as the `IProgress<T>` its expected to behave like this.

`Progress<T>` captures the `SyncronizationContext` when it's constructed, and when using `Report` it will try to invoke with the captured `SyncronizedContext`:
From the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh193692(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_6):

> Any handler provided to the constructor or event handlers registered with the ProgressChanged event are invoked through a SynchronizationContext instance captured when the instance is constructed.

If you will check your `SyncronizationContext.Current` before and after the `ShowDialog` you'll see that it changed from `WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext` to `SynchronizationContext`.

So the original `SyncronizationContext` is lost.

That's why if you construct the `Progress<T>` before the `ShowDialog` it works.

---

The reason for the loss of the `SyncronizationContext` can be found through the source code:

When the form is shown with `.ShowDialog` it causes a new message loop to be generated for it and a new `WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext` is installed for it only if no previous one exists ([see here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext.cs,119)) and then on closed it is uninstalled to the previous one ([here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext.cs,163)).

Since the context was already `WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext` when the second form shown, no new context was created, thus when closing causes the context to be set the the one before the main form was constructed.